# Eventlisteners impact?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**What impact does eventlisteres have?** Im talking about big numbers, here's an example:

- There's only **x** amount of `.marker` at first
- All children are added via `JS` when `.marker` is clicked - eventlistener
- Each child does it's own thing which means each of them have their own eventlisteners

---

```
<!-- Final HTML of single .marker when it has been clicked -->
<div class="marker">
    <div class="remove"></div>
    <div class="change"></div>
    <div class="add"></div>
    <div class="drag"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
var count = 20 000;

for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {

    var marker = document.createElement('div');
    marker.className = 'marker';
    someParentElement.appendChild(marker);

    marker.click( function() {
        //Create child elements
        var remove = document.createElement('div');
        remove.className = 'remove';
        marker.appendChild(remove);

        var change = document.createElement('div');
        change.className = 'change';
        marker.appendChild(change);

        var add = document.createElement('div');
        add.className = 'add';
        marker.appendChild(add);

        var drag = document.createElement('div');
        drag.className = 'drag';
        marker.appendChild(drag);

        //Children eventlisteners
        remove.click( function() {
            //Do it's thing
        });
        change.click( function() {
            //Do it's thing
        });
        add.click( function() {
            //Do it's thing
        });
        drag.click( function() {
            //Do it's thing
        });
    });
}
```

Please don't mind other things, *e.g* creating 20 000 elements programmatically. My question is this: **what would be the impact of having all these eventlisteners with all this code in them?** Does it even matter what or how much code is inside eventlistener as long as it hasn't been triggered?

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by 'impact'. There are JS frameworks that use a single toplevel event listener, though.

Comment: Could create single `click` event for `.marker` , use `event.target` to check which child element of `.marker` is source of event, use `if..else` to process what task to perform within single handler

Comment: @pvg What I mean by that is if there is and what impact does it have on performace / resources? Does it matter how many of them are on page? Can there be too much of them? Does the code inside the eventlistener adds weight to eventlistener's impact? Seems like lots of questions but it seems like a single big question in my opinion.

Comment: I'd like to point you to [this fabulous article](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) by eric lippert. Always remember to ask yourself if you even care.

Comment: @Amit Thanks for providing this article however I will need huge amount of eventlisteners and my example is not exaggerated by much. I really, really need to get the answer to this question.

Comment: And as the article explain, instead of asking this question - create the situation and **measure it**. See if it's good enough or not (and when you do, don't forget to see if everything is still functional *without* the listeners. having "*a huge amount*" of elements can be cause enough for a page to fall under load).

Comment: @guest271314 This looks promising, could you format your comment to answer with very minimal example?

Comment: @Solo of course it has an impact, the question is, is the impact important in your specific case. And the answer to that can only come from measurement. Also, as I mentioned, there is nothing stopping you from using a single event listener as, for instance, React.js does

Comment: I would be more concerned with the impact of just having that many html nodes in the document at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using event delegation , single event handler. See [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) , [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is)

```js
var count = 100;

for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {

  var marker = document.createElement('div');
  marker.className = 'marker';
  marker.innerHTML = marker.className + " " + i;
  document.body.appendChild(marker);

  //Create child elements
  var remove = document.createElement('div');
  remove.className = 'remove';
  remove.innerHTML = "remove" + i;
  marker.appendChild(remove);

  var change = document.createElement('div');
  change.className = 'change';
  change.innerHTML = "change" + i;
  marker.appendChild(change);

  var add = document.createElement('div');
  add.className = 'add';
  add.innerHTML = "add" + i;
  marker.appendChild(add);

  var drag = document.createElement('div');
  drag.className = 'drag';
  drag.innerHTML = "drag" + i;
  marker.appendChild(drag);
  //Create child elements
}

var check = function(args) {
  alert(args.innerHTML.replace(/[^\d+]/g, ""))
}

var obj = {
  remove: check,
  change: check,
  add: check,
  drag: check
}

var message = function(name) {
  console.log(name)
}

$("body").on("click", ".marker", function(event) {
  var name = event.target.className;
  switch (name) {
    case "remove":
      /* do stuff */
      message(name);
      break;
    case "change":
      /* do stuff */
      message(name);
      break;
    case "add":
      /* do stuff */
      message(name);
      break;
    case "drag":
      /* do stuff */
      message(name);
      break;
    default:
      /* do stuff */
      alert(name);
      break;
  }

  // utilizing `.is()`
  if ($(event.target).is(".remove")) {
    // do stuff
    event.target.innerHTML += "clicked"
  }
  if ($(event.target).is(".change")) {
    // do stuff
    event.target.innerHTML += "clicked"
  }
  if ($(event.target).is(".add")) {
    // do stuff
    event.target.innerHTML += "clicked"
  }
  if ($(event.target).is(".drag")) {
    // do stuff
    event.target.innerHTML += "clicked"
  }
  if (!$(event.target).is(".marker")) {
    // utilizing an object
    obj[event.target.className](event.target)
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: This is perfect. I imagine `('body').on()` / this code will also work if more `.marker`-s are added dynamically?

Comment: @Solo _"this code will also work if more .marker-s are added dynamically?"_ Yes

Answer (score 0):

Creating event handlers for so many things which are repeated feels like a waste of CPU cycles, plus memory to manage so many event listeners.

Instead, it would be preferrable to use event bubbling/delegation to listen to the click events from a parent node (as close an ancestor element as possible would be ideal) and see what element triggered the event and call the appropriate code accordingly.

This would be a one-time bind, and should also catch dynamically added elements if done right.

Examples with jQuery that are also explained quite well include the following

https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Though you are not limited to just jQuery to implement this.

Hope that helps.